# How to use bcrypt in JEST Unit Testing for a FindAll() Method

Tags: javascript, jestjs, nestjs

I have a NestJS App that has `GET` routes. One of them, for instance, is the `FindAll()` which simply gets all the users from `Prisma`. The `FindAll()` method looks like this:

```
  findAll(): Promise<Users[]> {
    return prisma.users.findMany();
  }
```

And in my `service.spec.ts` I have this:

```
const usersMany = [
  {
    username: 'user1',
    name: 'User One',
    password: '123',
    email: 'user1@test.com',
    tasks: [],
  },
  {
    username: 'user2',
    name: 'User Two',
    password: '456',
    email: 'user2@test.com',
    tasks: [],
  },
]

  describe('findAll', () => {
    it('should return all users', async () => {
      const usersAll = service.findAll();
      expect(usersAll).resolves.toEqual(usersMany);
    });
  });
```

How would I go about running this test case if I am also encrypting the passwords using `bcrypt`? In a running application, this would result in me getting all the users currently made with their passwords `hashed` instead of plain string.

Comment: You aren't returning the password, are you?

Comment: I am returning the bcrypt hashed password once a user is created. I understand that this may not be the best practice but I am practicing around and slowly improving things as I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure to **never** return the password, hashed or not. With a hashed password, you can still run `bcrypt.compare()` with a plain string and the hash and if you're lucky eventually determine the password. If you really do plan on keeping this approach, you can use Jest's `.arrayContaining` matcher with a regex for the password like

```js
expect(usersAll).toEqual(
  expect.arrayContaining(
    usersMany.map((user) => ({
      ...user,
      password: expect.stringMatching(/\$2a\$<SALT_VALUE_HERE>\$.+/)
    })
  )
)
```

This will allow the password to be hashed in the responses to match a regex rather than a strict value, as bcrypt does not hash the same value to the same hash twice. Make sure to replace the `<SALT_VALUE_HERE>` (the default value is 10)

Your other option would be mocking the bcrypt module to return some sort of expected string.

Your *best* option in my opinion would be to make sure your API never returns the password to the client.